# Is there any way to create multiple user stories

Tags: c#, rest, rally

I want to create multiple User Stories using the .NET REST API, but I only know how to create one-by-one.

I'm also getting a very slow response, average of 2 secs for each creation.

Can anybody help me?

Code that I'm using:

```
foreach(RCStoryRecord RecStory in ssStoryList)
{
    StoryObject = new DynamicJsonObject();
    RecStoryResult = new RCStoryResultRecord();  

    CreateResult creationResult = restApi.Create("HierarchicalRequirement", StoryObject);
}
```

Comment: You can definitely do more than one at a time. 2 seconds definitely sounds kind of slow. Can you post some of the code you've written so we can better assist?

Comment: I just add my code to the post above.

Comment: Thanks - I see by your code snippet that you're probably looking for a way to create multiple stories in a single call to restApi, without a for loop. Your approach is correct - there isn't a way to do multiple creates with one call - one call per story is required.

Comment: As for performance - can you tell us a bit more about your StoryObject's? Are they hydrated with data? Are the stories being parented to other objects, etc.? Thanks.

Comment: Usually our server responds in <200 ms. If you are seeing seconds between calls something odd is going on.